# Binding to an XElement

Tags: wpf

I need help binding to an XElement. Basically I am making a editor for certain elements in a web.config and I extract them as XElements and my View binds to a Collection of DataItems which has a property that contains my XElement.

When I do `Text="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"/>` I get all the text of the Element, but If I try `Text="{Binding Path=Data.Elements[], Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"/>` It doesn't work the TextBox is empty. I am trying to find a way to Template different sections dynamically to make them easier to edit instead of editing raw XMl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If u just want show one element only, try to use :

```
Text="{Binding XPath=@xxx"/>
```

Replace `xxx` with your own.

Comment: How did this get 2 votes and a checkmark?  XElement does not support XPath binding.